# Passing navigate as a prop

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

**In React Native, when using `createStackNavigator`, how can I pass `navigate` as a prop?**

- In the following example, `items` works fine, but `navigate` is `undefined` when passed to `MyList`.
- This means the button press throws an error: `undefined is not a function(evaluating 'navigate('ItemDetails', { itemId: item.id })')`.
- How can I pass `navigate` to `MyList`?

---

```
export class MyScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { items }  = this.props;
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        console.log(navigate); // this logs [Function anonymous] :)
        return (
            <View>
                <MyList items={items} navigate={navigate} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const MyList = ( { items }, { navigate } ) => {
    console.log(navigate); // this logs undefined :(
    return (
        <ScrollView>{ 
            items && items.map( item => 
                <View key={item.id}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () =>
                        navigate( 'ItemDetails', { itemId: item.id } )
                    }>
                        <Text>Go</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
        )}</ScrollView>
)}
```

PS: If I moved all the code from `MyList` directly into `MyScreen`, it would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `MyList` declaration to

```
const MyList = ( { items, navigate } ) => {...}
```

As, `MyList` is a functional component, any props passed to it will be available as the first parameter. I am just using object destructuring to get the required properties from that object.

Instead of passing `navigate` as props in `MyList`, you can also wrap the component using `withNavigation`, take a look at the document [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html). If you wrap it using `withNavigation`, you can directly access the navigator object from `props`.

Hope this will help!

Comment: If I change the declaration of `MyList` as you suggested, I get the error: `Object is not a function(evaluating 'navigate('ItemDetails', { itemId: item.id })')`. Do I need to change anything else? How do I get the required parameters from that object?

Comment: When you console.log(navigate) inside MyList what value do you get?

Comment: Found it! Inside `MyList`, I have to do `navigate.navigate`.